# Custom Woocommerce checkout select field saved value is a number instead of text

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, html-select, checkout

I have a little problem, I was doing selectable field in checkout page, when I select the option, in admin orders are printing numbers instead of text.

My code below:

```
 foreach($xml as $data){
     $location = $data -> A0_NAME;
     if (strpos($location, 'LT') !== false) {

         $vieta = $data -> NAME;
         $adresas = $data-> A2_NAME;
         $zip = $data -> ZIP;
        $fulladress = $vieta . ' ' . $adresas . ' ' . $zip;
         $option[] = $fulladress;
     }
 }

woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name1', array(
        'type'        => 'select',
        'required'    => true,
        'class'       => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'       => __('Select an option:', 'my_theme_slug'),
        'options'     => $option
        ),
     $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name1' ));
```

And there is a line which is updating my order:

```
 update_post_meta($order_id, 'my_field', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['my_field_name1']) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from your **`$option` array keys**… you certainly have something like:

```
$option = array( 'Text one', 'Text two', 'Text three');
```

or

```
$option = array( '1' => 'Text one', '2' => 'Text two', '3' => 'Text three');
```

So you when saving the data field to the order, it save the selected data key…

Instead you need to set it this way:

```
$option = array( 
    'Text one'   => 'Text one', 
    'Text two'   => 'Text two', 
    'Text three' => 'Text three',
);
```

---

**Update regarding your updated code:**

This way it will save the text instead of a key number… So your complete code:

```
$options = [];
foreach($xml as $data){
    $location = $data -> A0_NAME;
    if (strpos($location, 'LT') !== false) {

        $vieta = $data -> NAME;
        $adresas = $data-> A2_NAME;
        $zip = $data -> ZIP;
        $fulladress = $vieta . ' ' . $adresas . ' ' . $zip;
        $options[$fulladress] = $fulladress;
    }
}

woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name1', array(
    'type'        => 'select',
    'required'    => true,
    'class'       => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
    'label'       => __('Select an option:', 'my_theme_slug'),
    'options'     => $options,
), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name1' ) );
```

Now you will get a text value…

Comment: My array have been made with foreach method, so how can i put my values into this array?

Comment: @user3730912 update your question with all related code please (add all necessary code)… as we can't answer more than that. Note that: *"Questions seeking debugging  must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**."*

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: @user3730912 I have updated my answer (near the end)…